# Php remove specific item from Multidimensional array Shopping cart

Tags: php

I have an array I am using for a shopping cart. I am trying to remove a specific item from the cart. I have tried using the key value of the array and unset() this does not work 100% for me.

Below is an example of my code. Cant figure out the best approach

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])!='') :?>   
<div class="col-md-6 well pull-right My-cart">
    <ol class = "Shopping-list">
        <form class = "Delete-from-cart" method = "POST">
            <?php $sum = 0; ?>
            <?php foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $Key => $row) : ?> 
            <li><?php echo $row['Title'] .' * '.$row['quantity']; ?> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt delete-icon"></i>
                <?php $total =    $sum+= $row['Price'] * $row['quantity']; ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="Deleted-ID" value="<?php echo $Key; ?>">
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </form>   
    </ol>
    <div class="col-sm-6 well pull-right Total">
        <?php echo 'Your total is '.$total; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>

session_start();
$id = filter_var($_POST['Phone-ID'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$Phone_Title = filter_var($_POST['Phone-title'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$Phone_Price = filter_var($_POST['Phone-price'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$Phone_Quantity = filter_var($_POST['quantity'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$delete_phone = filter_var($_POST['Deleted-ID'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$_SESSION['cart'][] = array(
     'Title' => $Phone_Title,
     'Price' => $Phone_Price,
     'quantity' => $Phone_Quantity
);
unset($_SESSION['cart'][$delete_phone]);
var_dump($_SESSION['cart']);
```

Comment: Does your `$_POST['Deleted-ID']` actually matches position of `$_SESSION['cart']`?

Comment: I have added the form on my user end

Comment: Have you tried assign session cart to new variable, unset it's content and then re-assign to session cart new, modified value?

Comment: Can you try `$_SESSION['cart'][$delete_phone] = array();`?

Comment: What is in $delete_phone?

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning **$id** in the array

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $id = filter_var($_POST['Phone-ID'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $Phone_Title = filter_var($_POST['Phone-title'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $Phone_Price = filter_var($_POST['Phone-price'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $Phone_Quantity = filter_var($_POST['quantity'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $delete_phone = filter_var($_POST['Deleted-ID'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = array(//Here you need to assign $id must be same as $delete_phone at the time of deletion
         'Title' => $Phone_Title,
         'Price' => $Phone_Price,
         'quantity' => $Phone_Quantity
    );
    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$delete_phone]);
    var_dump($_SESSION['cart']);
?>
```